# Url rewrite rules error: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am create the rules in the `.htaccess` file in my domain folder.

My url on server is :

`https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/?loc=dashboard`

And I want change url to:

`https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/dashboard/`

In the .htaccess file, I write the rules are:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^everyoneknows\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/$1 [R,L]

##External redirect to /customer/dashboard url rules here.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^loc\=dashboard$
RewriteRule ^customer/$ https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/dashboard/? [R=301,L]
```

And the error message is shown:

```html
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

[image: picture]

Hope someone can guide me on how to correct in my rewrite url rules. Thanks.

**Original result:**

[image]

**Updated 1**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a redirect rule for old URL to new and an internal rewrite rule to handle pretty URL:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^everyoneknows\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://www.everyoneknows.com.my%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(customer)/\?loc=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(customer)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/?loc=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This assumes there is no .htaccess in `customer/` subdirectory. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer can redirect the page, but why the page css and jquery not included. You can see on my question updated 1.

Comment: It is due to use of relative URLs for those resources.  To fix, you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: This tag <base href="/" /> which page I need to put? Put in the .htaccess file?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment that it should be placed in the php/HTML source of your page just below `<head>` tag .

Comment: Ok, thanks. So in the between head tag, I add <base href="https://www.everyoneknows.com.my" />, right?

Comment: Just copy paste tag the way I wrote in my comment and it should be fine